# ActionBar won't show up on new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, android-actionbar

I am following the Android Development tutorials on Udacity and I have came across a problem in the app that I can't seem to work out how to fix.
I have created the new activity, and the Intent works perfectly fine in loading the new activity, the only problem is that when the second activity loads there is no actionbar that loads. Any Ideas?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**DetailActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                            String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                                            .setText(forecastStr);
                     }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

**activity_detail.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**content_detail.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.turnergasoil.sunshine.DetailActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
```

**fragment_detail.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.turnergasoil.sunshine.DetailActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_text"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The first Activity]

[image: The second activity with no action bar]

When changing the XML and Java file to include the toolbar, the frame layout and toolbar now overlap each other. See below.

[image]

When changing the XML and Java file to include the toolbar, the frame layout and toolbar now overlap each other. See below.

Comment: Suggestion: use Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should add Toolbar into the second activity's layout, and

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**EDIT**

activity_detail.xml should be like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: but even if he has the toolbar within his layout, at least it will be showing there.

Comment: There is no toolbar in the second layout.

Comment: then if there is no toolbar how `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` is going to help? it will just throw NPE. that is what im trying to say. there is no toolbar there otherwise the toolbar itself is a view and if it ever was within the layout it will be showing there

Comment: So I said "Should add Toolbar into the second activity's **layout**".

Comment: adding the toolbar caused the app to crash

Comment: @DeclanMorgan Add Toolbar into activity_detail first.

Comment: @zhaoyuanjie Fairly new to this, hence the android tutorial, I have tried to add `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`
However it says that there is multiple root tags...

Comment: Well, actionbar shown now. Seems actionbar is covered by fragment. That's another problem. Make sure the fragment container below the actionbar. Consider using margin_top or layout_below.